# Generate multiple rows based on a single row containing a null value after a right join

Tags: sql, postgresql, right-join

I have a software that retrieve data from multiple devices with SNMP.
The software then create a record in a table with a starting polling time and a ending polling time.

For every SNMP table we retrieve, we put the data in different tables.

In the model below, there is one snmp table (FrequencyValue). The tables are like so:

```
| Polls |                  |                  |
|-------|------------------|------------------|
| id    | start_time       | end_time         |
|-------|------------------|------------------|
| 1     | 2019-04-01T10:00 | 2019-04-01T10:10 |
| 2     | 2019-04-01T11:00 | 2019-04-01T11:10 |
| 3     | 2019-04-01T12:00 | 2019-04-01T12:10 |

| Devices    |
|------------|
| ip         |
|------------|
| 172.16.1.1 |

| FrequencyValue |         |                  |           |       |
|----------------|---------|------------------|-----------|-------|
|      device_ip | poll_id | timestamp        | frequency | value |
|----------------|---------|------------------|-----------|-------|
|     172.16.1.1 |       1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      1000 |    10 |
|     172.16.1.1 |       1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      2000 |    20 |
|                |         |                  |           |       |
|     172.16.1.1 |       3 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      1000 |    10 |
|     172.16.1.1 |       3 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      2000 |    20 |
```

The problem come when a device fails to answer, because as shown in the table `FrequencyValue`, the software didn't create a record for that table.

**The question:** In order to graph the column `value` per `frequency`, we would like to create `n` rows for each `frequency` that would have the column `value` to `null`.

So far, our query look like so:

```sql
select p.ip, coalesce(t.timestamp, p.start_time) as "time", t.frequency, t.value
from FrequencyValue as t
right join (
  select p.start_time, p.id, d.ip
  from Polls as p, Devices as d
) as p on (t.poll_id = p.id and t.device_ip = p.ip)
```

With output:

```
|         ip | timestamp        | frequency | value |
|------------|------------------|-----------|-------|
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      1000 |    10 |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      2000 |    20 |
|            |                  |           |       |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T11:00 |      null |  null |
|            |                  |           |       |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      1000 |    10 |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      2000 |    20 |
```

What we actually want is this:

```
|         ip | timestamp        | frequency | value |
|------------|------------------|-----------|-------|
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      1000 |    10 |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T10:02 |      2000 |    20 |
|            |                  |           |       |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T11:00 |      1000 |  null |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T11:00 |      2000 |  null |
|            |                  |           |       |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      1000 |    10 |
| 172.16.1.1 | 2019-04-01T12:02 |      2000 |    20 |
```

We tried putting another right join in the query but we just can't have the result we want.
The frequencies are not defined elsewhere, so to retrieve the frequencies available we could `select distinct` the frequencies in the table.
The DB is a PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select d.ip, t.timestamp, f.frequency,  fv.value
from devices d cross join
     (select distinct timestamp from frequencyvalue) t cross join
     (select distinct frequency from frequencyvalue) f left join
     frequencyvalue fv
     on fv.device_ip = d.ip and
        fv.timestamp = t.timestamp and
        fv.frequency = f.frequency;
```